# Find longest possible sequence for jumps on next bigger number

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Guys I am thinking on this problem several days and I have no solution even I have lots of experience.

Given a sequence of numbers, calculate the longest possible sequence of jumps from each number.

- You can only jump on a number that is greater than the current one
- You can jump on a number, only if there isn't one with a greater value between
- You can jump only from left to right

I have this solution but I need to make it much faster:

```
 private static List<Integer> slow(int[] numbers){

        int n = numbers.length;

        int initialJump = 0;
        int next = 0;

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        int counter = 0;
        int maxNum = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            initialJump = numbers[i];
            if (initialJump == maxNum) {
                list.add(0);
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                next = numbers[j];
                if (initialJump < next) {
                    counter++;
                    initialJump = next;
                }
            }
            list.add(counter);
            counter = 0;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Here is example:

Input

1 4 2 6 3 4

Output

2 1 1 0 1 0

Explanation

```
Element 1:
    1 -> 4 -> 6 (2 jumps)
Element 2:
    4 -> 6 (1 jump)
Element 3:
    2 -> 6 (1 jump)
Element 4:
    6 (0 jumps)
Element 5:
    3 -> 4 (1 jump)
Element 6:
    4 -> (0 jumps)
```

Do you have any idea?

Here is what I tried :

```
private static List<Integer> fast(int[] numbers){
    int n = numbers.length;

    int[] jumplist = new int[n];

    int initialJump = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int maxNum = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(i-1 >= 0 && map.get(i+1) != null && numbers[i+1] > numbers[i]){
            jumplist[i] = map.get(i+1)+1;
            continue;
        }

        initialJump = numbers[i];

        if (initialJump == maxNum) {
            jumplist[i] = 0;
            continue;
        }
        for(int j=i; j<n; j++) {
            if(initialJump < numbers[j]) {
                count++;
                initialJump = numbers[j];
                map.put(i,count);
            }
        }
        jumplist[i] = count;
        count = 0;
    }

    return Arrays.stream(jumplist).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is some test code:

```
        int randomLimit = 50000;
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomLimit; i++) {
            randomList.add(random.ints(0, randomLimit).findFirst().getAsInt());
        }
        System.out.println("Input: " + randomList.stream().limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        int[] randomArray = randomList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();

        Instant fastStarts = Instant.now();
        List<Integer> fastRes = fast(randomArray);
        System.out.println(fastRes.stream().limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        Instant fastEnds = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("fast: " + Duration.between(fastStarts, fastEnds).toMillis());

        Instant slowStarts = Instant.now();
        List<Integer> slowRes = slow(randomArray);
        System.out.println(slowRes.stream().limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        Instant slowEnds = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("slow: " + Duration.between(slowStarts, slowEnds).toMillis());

        if(slowRes.size() != fastRes.size()){
            System.out.println("Not Equal Result !!");
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < slowRes.size(); i++) {
                if (!slowRes.get(i).equals(fastRes.get(i))) {
                    System.out.println("Not Equal Result !!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide example data?  Your "definition" of "jump" is somewhat lacking.

Comment: I added example

Comment: Hint: work from the end of the list backwards.

Comment: I have tried... Please write some code if you have any idea. I will test it

Comment: Your posted code does not show any evidence of trying (to process the list backwards).

Comment: Does your "try" work but is still too slow, or does it produce the wrong answer, or does it produce an error?

Comment: Note that, when working backwards, once you find a bigger value to the right, you do not need to do any more searching to find the number of jumps (because you know the number of jumps *starting* at that bigger value).

Comment: @ScottHunter my try is just slower, it is working and produce correct answer

Comment: any help someone ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some optimized code but I need more optimized ...

```
   private static List<Integer> fast(int[] numbers){
        int n = numbers.length;
        int[] jumplist = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(jumplist, -1);
        int initialJump = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int maxNum = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();

        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {

            if(i+1 < n && jumplist[i+1] != -1 && numbers[i+1] > numbers[i]){
                jumplist[i] = jumplist[i+1] + 1;
                continue;
            }

            initialJump = numbers[i];
            if (initialJump == maxNum) {
                jumplist[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                if(initialJump < numbers[j]) {
                    count++;
                    initialJump = numbers[j];
                }
            }
            jumplist[i] = count;
            count = 0;
        }

        return Arrays.stream(jumplist).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: You are providing additional context to your question as an answer. If you need to add context, use the edit button and add it into your original post/question. The answer section should only be used when an answer to the asked question is being provided. 

You are welcome to answer your own question though and if this is the answer to your question that you found by yourself, please tag it as such.